# ngx clipboard subscribe to copyResponse$ not working

Tags: angular, clipboard, ngx-clipboard

I'm using [ngx-clipboard](https://github.com/maxisam/ngx-clipboard) to copy some text to clipboard in my Angular application.

```
  constructor(
    private clipboardService: ClipboardService,
  ) {
    this.subscribeToClipboard();
  }

  subscribeToClipboard() {
    this.clipboardService.copyResponse$.subscribe((res: IClipboardResponse) => {
      console.log('res', res);
      if (res.isSuccess) {

      } else {

      }
    });
  }

  triggerOnClick(content) {
    this.clipboardService.copyFromContent(content);
  }
```

The contents are actually copied to the clipboard when triggerOnClick is called. But the subscription to copyResponse$ does not work and I do not get any value in it when copy is done.

Angular: 8.1.0

ngx-clipboard: 12.3.0

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem as described. Versions are the same Angular 8 and ngx-clipboard 12.3.0.

I completely followed the installation and usage guide. I decided to go with the `ClipboardService`. I did not received any responses in `this.clipboardService.copyResponse$` Observable. I did some investigation and discovered that directive and its events are working as expected, but not the service.

It seems that the problem is in the `copyFromContent` method. It does not push any responses into the `copyResponse$` Observable.

Try to use `this.clipboardService.copy` method instead. Worked for me.